# Unable to set response header "Connection" in ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, keep-alive, kestrel-http-server, asp.net-core-6.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API and the requirement to set a `Connection: Close` header in certain situations to put some legacy terminals (client) in a maintenance mode.

I can set the headers in general, but the `Connection: Close` header gets removed and is not part of the response.

Here is my controller:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class HeaderTestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        Response.Headers.Add("Foo", "Bar");           // part of the response
        Response.Headers.Add("Connection", "close");  // NOT part of the response

        return NoContent();
    }
}
```

This is how my `Program.cs` looks like:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllers();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

When I invoke the API method, it returns the `foo` header but omits the `Connection` header:

[image]

Any idea which component is removing the `Connection` header and how I can bypass it?

Comment: What’s your frontend server? Kestrel only? Iis?

Comment: @DanielA.White Right now I use just Kestrel but I will deploy it to an Azure Web App in the future

Comment: check this method `CreateResponseHeaders` in [HttpProtocol.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/72ee5732f00289191a7f89ce8000854e52de808c/src/Servers/Kestrel/Core/src/Internal/Http/HttpProtocol.cs). it is removing this header here. and i don't think any ways to bypass it.

Comment: one more thing. this is only removed if client is making http/2 or http/3 request. if your legacy client is still using http/1.1 then it won't be removed.

Comment: @CodingMytra This is the information I was looking for and the answer to my question. I was able to retrieve the `Connection: Close` header with a http/1.1 request. Also, when I try the same request with http/2 or http/3, I don't get the Connection header. Can you add this as an answer so I can gladly accept it?. Thanks a ton.

Comment: as you mentioned, i converted this to ans. see below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check method `CreateResponseHeaders` in [HttpProtocol.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/72ee5732f00289191a7f89ce8000854e52de808c/src/Servers/Kestrel/Core/src/Internal/Http/HttpProtocol.cs). it is removing this header here. and I don't think any ways to bypass it.

and also this is only removed if client is making http/2 or http/3 request. if your legacy client is still using http/1.1 then it won't be removed.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this and add code to Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", builder =>
{
    builder.WithExposedHeaders(new string[] { "Connection"});
}));
```

**and also add this line too:**

```
app.UseCors("MyPolicy");
```

I have similar problem and solved

Comment: Please do not put screenshot as ans. and also this will be not solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help mohsen mashhadi. Unfortunately, this doesn't solve the problem - I tried it.

Comment: I edited my answer and hope that solves your problem.